# Java ArrayList - Are add() calls from one thread always readable from another?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

```
Thread 1: Call list.add()
Thread 1: Exits list.add()
Thread 2: Call list.get(list.size()-1)
```

I have a scenario where I can guarantee that `Thread 1` will complete the add() call before `Thread 2` make the get() call. Will `Thread 2` always see the changes made by `Thread 1` in this case? Or would the internal ArrayList variables need to be marked as volatile?

**Edit:** For those who are curious about why I can guarantee it. I have a sequence of events from a server that look like this:

```
Event A1
Event A2
Event A3
Event B
```

The events are dispatched sequentially by a single thread. I want to capture a list of all the `A` events so my code looks like this:

```
List<EventA> eventAList = new ArrayList<>();
connection.addListenerForEventAs(eventAList::add);

connection.waitForEventB();

//Here I am doing operations on the eventAList
```

Comment: No need do anychange. If your list is accessible by both thread and you are sure that first thread completes first.

Comment: If it is a *multi-threaded* environment, go for `Collections.synchronizedList()` or `COpyOnWriteArrayList`. Never make assumptions in *Multi-Threading*

Comment: @Panther, how could it behave in case of multi processor environment and caching happens to improve the performance

Comment: how are you **guaranteeing** that thread 1 will finish before thread 2?

Comment: @user3694267 Exactly what I was thinking. The internal "elementData" variable in ArrayList.java is not volatile, so I believe that writes to it are not guaranteed to be immediately visible to other threads.

Comment: To re-iterate what @I.K. says it depends crucially on exactly what you mean by the words "guarantee" and "before".

Comment: @bcoughlan, `ArrayList` is an unsynchronised data structure; expect no form of synchronisation, weak or strong.

Comment: Even with the added explanation, this still sounds fishy. Is there a guarantee that no event is added while the other thread reads the list? Is there the same guarantee for removing an event?

Comment: `Event B` is a marker that indicates the end of `Event A` messages, so yes, no event is added while the other thread reads the list. After waitForEventB() the listener for `Event A` is removed, and then the main thread has exclusive access to the list.

Comment: Looking at your code, I would suggest you use at [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) and leave it at that. `Collections.synchronizedList` is _painfully_ slow and `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is horrible of your have frequent writes, which you seem to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you will have to ensure that a *happens before* relationship exists between call of `add()` by thread-1 and call to `get()` by thread-2. Completion of call and *happens before* are totally different.

Unless you do that, your code will not be thread-safe. Why?. Thread-1 might finish the call to `add()` before thread-2 calls `get()`. But what is the guarantee that Thread-2 will not make a *local copy* of the list (keep it handy)?. `add()` method doesn't ensure a *happens-before*. So, there is no guarantee that the value added by the first thread is even written completely and is visible to thread-2 .

Use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `Collections.SynchronizedList()` in *Multi-threaded* environment.

Comment: This is what I suspected, despite all of the answers to the contrary! I updated my post with the explanation of why I can guarantee that Thread 1 will exit the add() call, just in case that changes anything.

Comment: @bcoughlan - Your code is not thread-safe. You are not doing anything that ensures that the changes made by one thread are visible to the other (I meant `join()` or `synchronization` ).

Comment: addendum: *happens before*  is a defined term in java,  explained e.g. in the official tutorials. Synchronized blocks guarantee a <i>happens before</i> relationship, also e.g. thread start or end or volatile read/writes. 
Also some common misunderstanding regarding visibility: Memory changes are **always** visible to other threads, but the order of the changes may not be as expected. The arraylist-size may have changed, but not yet the changed array-entry. To guarantee the wanted ordering a *happens-before* relationship is needed.

Comment: @bcoughlan, "This is what I suspected, despite all of the answers to the contrary! " - the other answers were given due to your magical claim that you could **guarantee** the thread behaviour and order!

Comment: @I.K. What I said is that I can guarantee that `Thread 1` will exit the add() call before Thread 2 makes the get() call.

Comment: @MarkusKull I'm trying to understand your "always visible" comment. If add() modifies both the size variable and the internal array, are they both visible to another thread when the call completes? Or does it mean that they both eventually become visible?

Comment: Both value changes eventually (practically in an instant) become visible, but another thread reading the values simultaneously may see another change-order than the writer. Even if the source or assembler code of the writer says otherwise. (Additionally one should also hope the compiler/JIT has not cached the values in registers). Crucial here is always the guarantee that *happens before* gives.

Comment: I would say `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` rather than either of those options.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.SynchronizedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) on the `list` or keyword synchronized with dedicated implementation for addition to ensure thread-safety,

```
public synchronized void addItem(Item item) {
    list.add(item);
}
```